# Is it possible to select the column from the result in an input type

Tags: php, html, mysql, select, pdo

Is this possible? I want to be able to select only the column that i specify in my html form, but i am not sure how to do this. I have searched for quite a while but wasn't able to find anything that matches my idea.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
echo "<select name='test'><option value='column1'>Column1</option></select>"
    echo "<input type='submit' name='grafiek' value='Maak grafiek'>";
    if(isset($_POST['checkvakje']) && $_POST['test'] && $_POST['grafiek']) {
      $tijd = $_POST['checkvakje'];

      foreach($tijd as $time) {
        try {
          $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT [the column i selected] FROM statistieken WHERE tijd = :tijd AND poortid = :poort");
          $stmt->execute(array(":tijd" => $time, ":poort" => $poort));

          if($stmt->rowCount() > 0) {
            while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
              echo "<tr>";
              echo "<td>".$row['column i selected']."</td>";
              echo "</tr>";
            }
          }
        }
        catch(PDOexception $e) {
          echo "Query ging fout: " . $e->getMessage() ."";
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: you can select user select column but you don't use form value directly into query . use some condition to check it's valid column are not and then use .

Comment: the column that you select is stored in `$_POST['test']`, isn't it ?

Comment: @Ollaw, thats correct. I tried a few things myself but withouth any luck whatsoever.

Comment: you can directly get selected column value in $_POST['test']

Comment: @AmitSahu Maybe not directly - it's better to use some form-name to db-column mappings, that will serve as whitelist and hide db details.

Comment: @shudder you are right dear, It become more easy if used name attribute with db-column name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not via parameter binding.

Knowing the column names, you have to validate if the input matches a whitelist, so that there are no errors and more importantly - that it is secure.

For example:

```
$allowedColumns = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz'];

if (in_array($_POST['column'], $allowedColumns, true)) {
    $column = $_POST['column'];
} else {
    // Error: Invalid input
}

$sql = "SELECT {$column} FROM dummy WHERE whatever = 'example'";
```

Comment: why not via parameter binding ?

Comment: Exactly what i wanted, greatly appreciate the help!

Comment: Because it's not a parameter; i.e. not a field *value*. It is very rare that column names are selected by the user.

Answer (score 0):

select all column and just control it in php side  like this

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
{

          echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>".$row[$_POST['test']]."</td>";
          echo "</tr>";
}
```

note : using user data as column name looks have so much of security issue